Filtering by taxonomy term reference in jsonapi
I'm trying to filter by a taxonomy term entity reference field (field_status, referencing the vocabulary action_status) but I'm getting a weird error.
Here's the curl request:
curl -G -s -b d8_cookie.txt \
  -d filter[taxonomy_term--action_status][condition][path]=field_status.name \
  -d filter[taxonomy_term--action_status][condition][operator]=IN \
  -d filter[taxonomy_term--action_status][condition][value][]=Live \
  "$D9_URL/jsonapi/node/action"

and here's the error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base_table.tid' in 'on clause': SELECT \"base_table\".\"vid\" AS \"vid\", \"base_table\".\"nid\" AS \"nid\"\nFROM\n\"node\" \"base_table\"\nINNER JOIN \"node__field_status\" \"node__field_status\" ON \"node__field_status\".\"entity_id\" = \"base_table\".\"nid\"\nLEFT OUTER JOIN \"taxonomy_term_data\" \"taxonomy_term_data\" ON \"taxonomy_term_data\".\"tid\" = \"node__field_status\".\"field_status_target_id\"\nINNER JOIN \"taxonomy_term_field_data\" \"taxonomy_term_field_data\" ON \"taxonomy_term_field_data\".\"tid\" = \"taxonomy_term_data\".\"tid\"\nINNER JOIN \"node_field_data\" \"node_field_data\" ON \"node_field_data\".\"nid\" = \"base_table\".\"nid\"\nLEFT OUTER JOIN \"group_relationship_field_data\" \"gcfd\" ON base_table.nid=gcfd.entity_id AND gcfd.plugin_id IN (:plugin_ids_in_use__0, :plugin_ids_in_use__1)\nLEFT OUTER JOIN \"group_relationship_field_data\" \"gcfd_2\" ON base_table.tid=gcfd_2.entity_id AND gcfd_2.plugin_id IN (:plugin_ids_in_use__0, :plugin_ids_in_use__1)\nWHERE (\"taxonomy_term_field_data\".\"name\" IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) AND (\"node_field_data\".\"type\" = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (\"gcfd\".\"entity_id\" IS NULL) AND (\"gcfd_2\".\"entity_id\" IS NULL)\nGROUP BY \"base_table\".\"vid\", \"base_table\".\"nid\"\nLIMIT 51 OFFSET 0; Array\n(\n    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => Live\n    [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => action\n    [:plugin_ids_in_use__0] => group_node:action\n    [:plugin_ids_in_use__1] => group_node:message_template\n)\n"

What am I doing wrong?
Edit: I've worked around this for now by using filter[field_status.meta.drupal_internal__target_id][value]=105 which does work, but isn't ideal.

Try creating the URL manually and seeing if you still get the same error; it may be that curl is not generating the URL in a way that Drupal can understand.

I've done that, with the same result, and I've confirmed that other filters work fine using curl, it only seems to be taxonomy term references that trigger this error.

The question is not clear, at least for me.
Are you GETting some content type - e.g. nodes of article bundle - which have a field_status reference field?
And your trying to filter that GET?
Namely, your full JSON:API query, without include or filter is
https://yoursite.com/jsonapi/node/article ?
In that case the filter is simply using short-hand syntax
https://yoursite.com/jsonapi/node/article?filter[field_status.name][value]=term_name_1
Or with long syntax
https://yoursite.com/jsonapi/node/article?filter[taxonomy-filter][condition][path]= field_status.name&filter[taxonomy-filter][condition][value]=term_name_1
I've tested it on a clean Drupal 10.3.x installation as anon user request and it works, if this doesn't work on your installation you should check other contrib modules installed or your custom code.

Yeah we use the group module quite heavily and I think that might be interfering here.

If those nodes or taxonomy are inside a group, most definitely it is. JSON:API needs extra hooks to filter beetween related content, see https://www.drupal.org/node/3036792 . Group has never implemented those hooks. See: https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/3052238 which refers to the old 8.1.x version, still, the 3.x.x doesn't implement those. So I'd suggest you to temporarily disable the group module locally to check if it is actually the cause. In that event, you'll definitely need to implement those hooks.

Thanks, those links are really useful
